# Excel convert excel date formula to VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this Excel formula below;

```
=DATE(YEAR(G8),MONTH(G8),8)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(G8),MONTH(G8),4))+14
```

I would like to convert this Excel formula into a VBA 
Is it possible to do this in Excel VBA? Please help

Comment: "The 8th of the month minus the weekday number of the 4th of that month plus 14 days" Is that right?

Comment: Look at `DateAdd` and `DateSerial` functions...

Comment: yes @ JNevill, the formula will return the 3rd Wednesday of every month

Comment: Did you try converting it on your own? I'm guessing the down-votes are because of a lack of attempt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is true to the math. Seems to be outputting the same thing:

```
Public Function thirdWednesday(inDate As Date) As Date
    thirdWednesday = ((inDate - Day(inDate) + 8) - Weekday(inDate - Day(inDate) + 4)) + 14
End Function
```